# Sent Items folder not available in James Server 3

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, inbox, james

I am using James server 3 beta with MySQL database as a repository to develop a mail client application. I am able to send/receive mails from the application. But I want to store a copy of the sent emails in the Sent Item folder which is not provided by James server. Am I going to create the Sent Items folder my self or is there other workarounds for this with James server?
regards,

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing magic about the Sent items folder.  You have to create it yourself and copy messages to it explicitly.

Comment: I am using MySQL as the mail repository and whenever a user is created by using Telnet(default management for James) its INBOX will be created automatically. Now, how can I create the Sent Items mailbox whenever a user is created?

Comment: I don't know, I guess you need a James expert for that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the "Sent" folder. James will create it for every user. Only if you use maildir as repository, not a MySQL.

If you store the mails to a MySQL database then you should look for mails in the database. Look for table james_mailbox, and filter column mailbox_name to "Sent".

You can store the mails to a directory, then you will have access to all emails, not only sent. But remember, this feature is available only for Linux.

One more. The mailet ToSenderFolder should be present in conf/mailetcontainer.conf file.